# Discrete Math on Functions as bijection

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can Someone help me on how to Prove that $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(a, b) = (−b, a)$ is a well-defined bijection.

Comment: Can you think of an inverse function?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Each $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is unique. Hence, each $(-b,a)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is also unique. Use the definition of well-defined bijection:

Each element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ must be paired with at least one element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, no element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ may be paired with more than one element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, each element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ must be paired with at least one element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, and no element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ may be paired with more than one element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. I can't tell any more, or else the answer is obvious.

Comment: I know that bijection means that is one-to-one and onto. but how would I show this?

Comment: @ArashXXX There exists a unique $(-b,a)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ for all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Can you show me more steps on how to do this? I'm so confused

Comment: @ArashXXX See my edited answer.